# More concise way of writing css/sass keyframe code

Tags: javascript, css, sass, css-animations

I want modals to hide using the reverse of the animation by which they appeared.

So far, the strategy I have come up with is to create CSS rules with a "reverse" counterpart:

```
.modal-animate-zoom {
  animation: animatezoom 0.77s;
}

.modal-animate-zoom-reverse {
  animation: animatezoom-reverse 0.77s;
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom-reverse {
  from {transform: scale(1)} 
  to {transform: scale(0)}
}
```

And doing something like this in JavaScript when I want to hide the modal:

```
modal.classList.remove('modal-animate-popup')
modal.classList.add('modal-animate-popup-reverse')
// modalsList is the children of parent container
setTimeout(_ => { modalsList.removeChild(modal); }, 770)
```

This works. The problems I have with this are:

1. There's a lot of duplication in the CSS (you may not call it code, but it's in my code base and I will have no dumb duplication that I can avoid)
2. The timeout duration in JS needs to match the animation duration, and obviously I don't want to duplicate these values in JS and CSS.

I'm thinking of these two options:

1. Tidy the CSS as best I can (I'm using SCSS) and maybe listening to transition finished event in JavaScript
2. Using CSSOM to set the styles, taking the timeout value from a JS variable (but then I'm not sure I can use something like autoprefixer, but maybe my Js code can do that?)

Can anyone recommend either way, or an alternate solution?

Comment: I think this is a better fit on [codereview.se]

Comment: @Amy I see where you're coming from for the css bit, but the potential answers may also recommend jumping to a different tech altogether e.g. CSSOM - or propose an alternative solution. Is that under CodeReview's remit?

Comment: Of course, why wouldn't it be?  Your code works and you're seeking improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `animatezoom-reverse` animation and change the `animation-direction` based on the inclusion of the reverse class. Note that `forwards` and `reverse` do two totally different things.

**[animation-fill-mode: forwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)**

> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe
>   encountered during execution.

**[animation-direction: reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)**

> Animation steps are performed backwards, and timing functions are also
>   reversed.

```css
.modal-animate-zoom {
  animation: animatezoom 0.77s forwards;
}

.modal-animate-zoom-reverse {
  animation: animatezoom 0.77s reverse forwards;
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0);} 
  to {transform: scale(1);}
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box modal-animate-zoom">box</div>
<div class="box modal-animate-zoom-reverse">box</div>
```

A more refined version of the above with less repetition:

```css
.modal-animate-zoom {
  animation: animatezoom 0.77s forwards;
}

.reverse-animation {
  animation-direction: reverse;  
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0);} 
  to {transform: scale(1);}
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box modal-animate-zoom">box</div>
<div class="box modal-animate-zoom reverse-animation">box</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is `animation: animatezoom 0.77s reverse forwards;` meant to include `forwards` though?

Comment: @andyhasit Yes, totally different property: `The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe `. In other words, I didn't want the animations to reset to the starting state after completing.

Comment: The refined version is close to what I had before on my own, but doesn't work when class added by js: https://jsfiddle.net/eapvchLz/

Comment: @andyhasit Okay, but I'm not sure what you'd like me to do with that, Andy. Does the first version meet  your needs?

Comment: I know, that was more FYI. The first version does tidy the CSS up a bit, thank you. I still have the animation duration duplicated, both withing the css and across css & js, but maybe there isn't a CSS solution to that.